# In DataPrep, How to create connection with instance of sql without public ip on google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, vpc, google-cloud-dataprep, google-vpc

In Dataprep, when creating the connection there is the 'Test Connection' button, after filling in all the connection data, with the private ip, port, username and password, I click on the test button and I get the error [Unable to connect to host] SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out.

I correctly configured the subnetwork settings in the 'execution settings' preferences, as indicated in this link
https://community.trifacta.com/s/article/Configure-Dataprep-to-run-Dataflow-jobs-in-a-custom-VPC

My SQL instance on google cloud platform has no public ip, only private ip, I'm not getting dataprep to connect to the database, how should I proceed, is there any additional configuration for it to work?

I'm also not able to find material and documentation about this, if you can help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Dataprep isn't connected to your VPC and can't access to your private IP.

Answer (score 0):

I found [such a description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gakkF.png) in [the official document](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/Connection+Types).

> NOTE: Relational datasources must be available on a public IP address that is accessible from the deployment of Dataprep by Trifacta Premium.

As others have answered, you cannot.